# Next Js App error in cpanel shared hosting; WebAssembly.instantiate(): Out of memory: wasm memory at lazyllhttp

Tags: node.js, next.js, cpanel, shared-hosting

I am trying to run a simple next js app in cpanel shared hosting. I followed the this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@geevadon/how-to-deploy-a-next-js-app-on-cpanel-efficiently-c00c5eb860de

I tried to run next app by custom Server. Here is my server.js:

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const hostname = 'localhost'
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
// when using middleware `hostname` and `port` must be provided below
const app = next({ dev, hostname, port })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
    createServer(async (req, res) => {
        try {
            // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
            // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
            const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
            const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl

            if (pathname === '/a') {
                await app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
            } else if (pathname === '/b') {
                await app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
            } else {
                await handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error occurred handling', req.url, err)
            res.statusCode = 500
            res.end('internal server error')
        }
    })
        .once('error', (err) => {
            console.error(err)
            process.exit(1)
        })
        .listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`)
        })
})
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
  "name": "next-simple",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "export": "next build && next export",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.15",
    "next": "13.4.16",
    "postcss": "8.4.28",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3"
  }
}
```

here is my `next.config.js` file:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

After setting up node.js app in my cpanel,
[Click here to see the Cpanel Nodejs Setup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSyfH.png)

`.htaccess` file is like this:

```
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN
PassengerAppRoot "/home/toirihoi/nextapp"
PassengerBaseURI "/"
PassengerNodejs "/home/toirihoi/nodevenv/nextapp/18/bin/node"
PassengerAppType node
PassengerStartupFile server.js
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php80” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php80 .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php8_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 3000
   php_value max_input_time 6000
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 2512M
   php_value post_max_size 8M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php80"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 3000
   php_value max_input_time 6000
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 2512M
   php_value post_max_size 8M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php80"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
```

Then I tried to start the app from cpanel terminal by npm run start command and getting the following error:

```
> next-simple@0.1.0 dev
> node server.js

undefined:9898
      return await WebAssembly.instantiate(mod, {
                               ^

RangeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Out of memory: wasm memory
    at lazyllhttp (eval at requireWithFakeGlobalScope (/home/toirihoi/nodevenv/nextapp/18/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@edge-runtime/primitives/load.js:64:3), <anonymous>:9898:32)

Node.js v18.16.1
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

I tried from ssh terminal putty to run the app by npm start command.

Please see the result from putty terminal.

```
[nextapp (18)] [toirihoi@server3 nextapp]$ npm start

> next-simple@0.1.0 start
> NODE_ENV=production node server.js

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1740:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1788:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1876:7)
    at /home/toirihoi/nextapp/server.js:37:10
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -98,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3000
}
```

I changed the port to 3001. It run successfully but when open my app on Chrome browser it says 404 not found.

```
[nextapp (18)] [toirihoi@server3 nextapp]$ npm start

> next-simple@0.1.0 start
> NODE_ENV=production node server.js

> Ready on http://localhost:3001
http://localhost:3001
```